# points inside a circle in Gmap v3

Tags: geometry

I draw a circle centered at any point. Now i want to show all point markers within that circuller region. I used circle.getBounds() and then contains() method, but it shows some of points outside of circle also(latlngBounds type). I also dont want to use mathematical functions that uses sin(lat)...cos(..) things because i think it will slow my application as i am using million of point markers. Can you suggest me an feasible solution or any example will be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You "think" your application will be slow, but have you tried?

Comment: No i dint try yet, actually i suggested this thing to my seniors and they told try for some other options if available. So please tell me if there any way to avoid that mathematical functions. I am not sure how that will effect performance. Have anyone tested it for performance measure.

Comment: Thanks, I tried mathematical formula to get all points inside a circle and it is working fine.

Comment: It takes less than a second to search and show around 3000 markers.

Comment: function calc_distance(cen,pointMarker){
    var lat2=cen.lat();
    var lon2=cen.lng(); 
    
    var lat1=pointMarker.getPosition().lat();
    var lon1=pointMarker.getPosition().lng();
    
    var R = 6371; // km 
    var dLat = (lat2-lat1)* Math.PI / 180; 
    var dLon = (lon2-lon1)* Math.PI / 180;    
    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + 
            Math.cos(lat1* Math.PI / 180) * Math.cos(lat2* Math.PI / 180) *  
            Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);  
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));  
    return R * c; 
    
   }

Answer (score 0):

Won't Pythagorus suffice? I've had to do something similar, and I'm using the standard a^2 = b^2 + c^2 to calculate it. See my stack overflow question - http://bit.ly/gJFuWM

I assume by the use of sin, and cos you are also taking into account the curvature of the earth?